# Proper way to retrieve the result of tasks in asyncio

Tags: python-asyncio

I am trying to examine the `wait` method of the asyncio module. I have this primitive test app to serve as a playground:

```
import asyncio

async def foo():
    return 1  # datetime.datetime.now()

async def entry_point():
    coros = [foo()]*3
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(coros, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    for obj in done:
        print(obj._result)  # works, but seem dirty

asyncio.run(entry_point())
```

Basically, my goal is to get the result of the first completed task. And here's I am a bit confused in terminology. The docs says that `asyncio.wait`

> Returns two sets of Tasks/Futures: (done, pending).

How do I know whether the object is a `task` or a `future`?
And the main question is, how do I extract the result of the successfully ended task ?
One way is to access the protected attribute `_result` (as is shown in my code snippet). But I am feeling like there's a cleaner way to do that. What is the proper pattern to achieve that?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives

Comment: Have you looked into the `FIRST_COMPLETED` option documented in your link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc for [asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) has the following note:

> Deprecated since version 3.8, will be removed in version 3.11: Passing
> coroutine objects to wait() directly is deprecated.

Therefore you should use [asyncio.Task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) that also has the [asyncio.Task.result](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.result) method:

**test.py:**

```
import asyncio
import random


async def task(i):
    t = random.uniform(1, 5)
    print(f"START: {i} ({t:.3f}s)")
    await asyncio.sleep(t)
    print(f"END: {i}")

    return i


async def main():
    tasks = []

    for i in range(5):
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(task(i)))

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

    for t in done:
        print(t.result())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

**Test:**

```
$ python test.py
START: 0 (2.743s)
START: 1 (2.490s)
START: 2 (4.785s)
START: 3 (3.746s)
START: 4 (1.010s)
END: 4
4
```

If you want to retrieve all results and get the earliest next result first,  use [asyncio.as_completed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) instead:

```
...
for t in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
    print(await t)
...
```

**Test 2:**

```
$ python test.py
START: 0 (2.155s)
START: 1 (1.309s)
START: 2 (3.380s)
START: 3 (3.451s)
START: 4 (1.587s)
END: 1
1
END: 4
4
END: 0
0
END: 2
2
END: 3
3
```